# Save and Delete buttons not working

Tags: java, save

I want to save whatever I write in a textfield and delete the line the program finds after clicked on search button. why doesn't it work? Here are my two buttons:

```
private class dDelete implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        HM.remove((String)result.getText());
    }
}

private class sSave implements ActionListener {
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {    
     Set <String> ISet = HM.keySet();
     Iterator itr = ISet.iterator();
     String tuple = "";

     java.io.File iwrite = new java.io.File("c:\\temp\\savetest.txt");
     if (iwrite.exists()){
         System.out.println("The file exists");
         System.exit(0);
     }
     java.io.PrintWriter output = null;
     try {
         output = new java.io.PrintWriter(iwrite);
     } catch(Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
     }

     while (itr.hasNext()) {
         String Keys = (String)itr.next();
         String val = HM.get(Keys);
         tuple = Keys + " " + val;

         output.print(tuple);
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should close your output writer `output.close()` that could be why.

You are not showing what you are adding to the set HM so hard to tell if the remove will work. Check the return value of the call to HM.remove and you will see if it succeeds, else you are using the wrong keys (not using the same/equal one when adding as removing).

Other than that I would recommend iterating over the entrySet when you need both the key and the value (`HM.entrySet()`).

Also rename your classes and variables according to Java naming conventions (classes start with a capital letter, instance variables shouldn't etc).  For more info. see the [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307).

Comment: +1 - I added a link to the details on the naming conventions.  (Good edit as well - hopefully someone will ratify it soon.)